# What is the save file location for Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning, windows

I want to create backups from my save files for *Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning*.

**But I can't find them! Where are they?**

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about the PC version here right?

Comment: yeah **PC**, not ps3 or xbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Steam Cloud enabled game so all your game saves are synched to the Steam Cloud so you can log in with them where ever you are.

However, your settings files and game saves will find their way into the folder:

```
%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\My Games\Reckoning
```

I can verify that I have seen game saves in that folder in the past, but it may only be used in the event Steam Cloud is not accessible or you are playing in offline mode.  Otherwise, all your games saves are managed by the Steam Cloud.

Comment: Thanks, even in offline mode, save file must be exist in somewhere!  but **Where?**

Comment: I checked in this location but didn't find any game saved files.

Comment: If you are connected to Steam, all of your files are synced to the Steam cloud, which is why I mention they won't always be there....

Comment: Like others, my saves are not in this folder. I found mine in Steam\userdata\<userID#>\102500\remote.

Answer (score 3):

They are stored in your documents folder in the path:

```
%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\My Games\Reckoning
```

Comment: there is only some file's with 1 kb size

Answer (score 0):

Do a full search in your hard drive looking for the folder

> 102500

This is the steamId of the game. Your saves will be inside this folder.

P.S.: (In Windows8, open Windows Explorer and use its search)